# Need to make a port detector

Tags: apache, networking, port, daemon, netstat

I am trying to make a service which can detect when a port gets occupied.
So `netstat -lntu | grep tcp` can list all occupied ports. So a difference between the output from first `netstat` executioin and one after the a port gets occupied can get me the port value.

And it needs to be fully automated so i made a infinite loop which will continuously check for differences between two consecutive `netstat`.

Here is my code in js and i am running it using [node-daemonize2](https://github.com/niegowski/node-daemonize2):

```
var shell = require("shelljs");
var InfiniteLoop = require("infinite-loop");
var il = new InfiniteLoop();
var diff = require('diff');

var oldStr = '';
var newStr = '';

shell.exec("netstat -lntu | grep tcp",{silent:true}, function (code, output, error) {
  oldStr = output;      
});

il.add(function () {
  shell.exec("netstat -lntu | grep tcp",{silent:true}, function (code, output, error) {
    newStr = output;
    if(!newStr.replace(oldStr,'')==''){
     var dD = diff.diffChars(oldStr, newStr)[1];
     if(dD.added){
       let value = dD.value.replace(/\n/g,'');
       re = /[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/
       value = re.exec(value);
       console.log(value[0]);
     }
    }
    oldStr = newStr;
  });
});

il.run();
```

Now this thing works perfectly fine, but is resource heavy. So is there a way to make it light or a completely new and more efficient way to approach this problem?

Comment: What frequency do you need for this verification?  If your loop is constantly running, it will eat up your CPU.  You could add a sleep between each loop to reduce the impact on the server, and still get results that make sense for your need.

Comment: I need to detect the port as soon as they get occupied. So maybe instead of a loop maybe some sort of event trigger might work?

Comment: Look into this: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/notification-trigger-on-port-activity-887073/.  Apparently iptables and snort can help.